# boto3 ObjectVersion missing load()?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to get object metadata from versioned S3 bucket like this

```
import boto3
s3res = boto3.resource('s3')
vers_object = s3res.ObjectVersion('bucket', 'key', 'versionId')
vers_object.last_modified
```

according to the [documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.ObjectVersion.last_modified), this should work and should load last_modified attribute via load() method. Except it instead gives this exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 343, in property_loader
    self.__class__.__name__))
boto3.exceptions.ResourceLoadException: s3.ObjectVersion has no load method
```

I can probably use `.get()` method and take the relevant data from there, but I was hoping that the `last_modified` attribute give me better string for parsing and would expect it to be faster.

According to `pip show`, I have boto3 in version 1.4.0 and botocore in version 1.4.53.

Comment: which version of both are you using ? try to upgrade to latest version

Comment: @FrédéricHenri current.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that works using Python 3.5, at first I faced the same issue as you did but then I got it working using the get() method..Let me know if you need any more information.

```
object_version = s3res.ObjectVersion('bucketname','objectname','VersionId')

data=object_version.get()

print(data)

print(data['LastModified'])
```